# Assign more than one IP Address to the same MAC Address on Linux ISC-DHCP Server

Tags: linux, ip, ethernet, mac-address, isc-dhcp

I have the following question: One Linux DHCP server in pool mode, because of the step of fabrication, all the products have the same MAC Address that is changed at end of line, the boards use ethernet to record they file system, and for volume of production, we need to record six or more boards at same time per computer ( We use a switch in the production line). When monitoring the boards they often get same IP of another board. Exist a configuration on server that enable assign multiple ip's to the same MAC Address?

Comment: If you have duplicate MAC addresses, you will run into problems even without DHCP...

Answer (score 1):

I think you will not be able to do this without separating all your boards so they don't see each other. Fortunately, you don't need to physically separate them, there is a solution that allows you to achieve this logically.

To give you an idea of what is needed:

- You need a managed switch, where you configure a different VLAN on each port you will connect one of your devices to (i.e. "access" or "untagged" port).
- You connect your server to a "trunk" or "tagged" port.
- For each VLAN, you need on the server a logical network interface (`eth0.VLAN_ID`), a network namespace (see `man ip-netns(8)`) and an instance of the DHCP server running in that particular instance. If you need other services, it's best to create a separate instance of that service in each namespace as well.

With this setup, your clients will no longer see each other. You won't have any conflicts anymore. Setting it up is probably not easy, but you should be able to script this quite well.

I answered a similar question some time ago involving network namespaces. It might give you some ideas:

[The same IP on multiple interfaces](https://serverfault.com/questions/705919/the-same-ip-on-multiple-interfaces/706274#706274)